# Why there result is zero, not the right sqrt?

Tags: c, function

As in the title, when I want to know the result of 'liczba' and i choose 25, the result is 0.0000? The problem is in selected lines where i wrote comments .
Thanks for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ACCURACY (1.e-5) 
double pierwiastek(double liczba);

int main( void ) {

  double liczba;

  for(;;){

    printf("\nPodaj wartosc liczby dodatniej (-1 konczy program):\n");
    scanf("%lf",&liczba);

    if(liczba<0.0) break;

    pierwiastek(liczba);
    printf("\nliczba %20.15lf, zalozona dokladnosc obliczania pierwiastka: %20.15lf\n", 
       liczba, ACCURACY);
    printf("\tpierwiastek liczby: obliczony %20.15lf, dokladny %20.15lf\n", 
       pierwiastek(liczba), sqrt(liczba));//<---- there
      printf("\nPierwiastek z pierwiastka: %lf",pierwiastek(pierwiastek(liczba)));//<-----there

  }
  return 0;
}

double pierwiastek(double liczba)
{
    double pierwiastek = 1.0f;
    double temp;
    //wzor Herona
    do{
      temp = pierwiastek;
      pierwiastek = 0.5f * (temp + liczba/temp);

    } while(fabs(pierwiastek*pierwiastek - liczba)/liczba > ACCURACY); 

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't return anything from your function. I think you meant to say:

```
double pierwiastek(double liczba)
{
  ..
  return pierwiastek;
}
```

---

A few notes in your code though:

This:

```
ierwiastek(liczba);
```

has no effect, since the function passes `liczba` by value, and you don't store the return of the function anywhere, which doesn't make sense. Usually, you would do:

```
double result = pierwiastek(liczba);
```

Here:

```
printf("\nPierwiastek z pierwiastka: %lf", pierwiastek(pierwiastek(liczba)));
```

I do not what you mean to say, but calling the function, and passing its result to another function call of the same function, seems a bit unusual. I would suggest you to double think about that line of code again.

Comment: Yea! BIG THANK U!

Comment: You are welcome @KamilaNowak. Next time, I suggest you to use English for your code (e.g. for function names and variables). I did the same as you in first semester, I learned from that ;) PS: Since the answer helped, you might want to accept it, by ticking the green marker on its left.

Comment: @KamilaNowak. Recommend compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` so the compiler warns you if you do something like this in the future. Typically every compiler warning should be addressed (and only in very few cases is it unjustified).